# How to add reference to the project in android?

Tags: android, reference

I have one simple android project in that i want to refer another project classe

Is it possible or not possible means please tell me how

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can convert one of your projects to library ans set up 2nd project to use it. As [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html). Or (if your project consists of Java code only) you can generate a JAR distribution and add that to /libs folder of your 2nd project